# Obtener url https firebase angular

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, angular7, storage

estoy intentando obtener la url de una imagen almacenada en firebase y no consigo obtenerla.

El funcionamiento es el siguiente, el usuario sube la imagen y yo almaceno en la bbdd la ruta por ejemplo images/nombreImagen.

como puedo recuperar esa foto y mostrarla? me gustaria obtener la url

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubkp5.png

lo que hago es basicamente esto

```html
enviarProgreso() {
  debugger;
  //SUBIDAS A FIREBASE
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('peso', this.peso);
  data.append('fecha', this.fecha);
  //FOTOESPALDA
  if(this.fileEspalda != null){
  const randomIdEspalda = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  const filepathEspalda = `evolucionClientes/${randomIdEspalda}`;
  const fileRef = this._storage.ref(filepathEspalda);
  const task = this._storage.upload(filepathEspalda, this.fileEspalda);
  data.append('fileToUploadEspalda', filepathEspalda);  
  this.fileEspalda = null;
  }
   //FOTOPERFIL
  if(this.filePerfil!=null){
   const randomIdPerfil = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
   const filepathPerfil = `evolucionClientes/${randomIdPerfil}`;
   this._storage.upload(filepathPerfil, this.filePerfil);
   data.append('fileToUploadPerfil', filepathPerfil);
   this.filePerfil = null;
  }

 //FOTOFRENTE
  if(this.fileFrente!=null){
  const randomIdFrente = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  const filepathFrente = `evolucionClientes/${randomIdFrente}`;
  const fileRef = this._storage.ref(filepathFrente);
  const task = this._storage.upload(filepathFrente, this.fileFrente);
  data.append('fileToUploadrente', filepathFrente);
  this.fileFrente = null;
  }

  this.HomeService.saveNuevoProgreso(data).subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.status === 'ok') {
      this.displayForm = false;
      this.datosGuardadosOK = true;
      this.ngOnInit();
    } else {
      this.datosError = true;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: adrianmcguire, si no vemos lo que has intentado no podremos saber cual es tu error... Por favor edita la pregunta y muéstranos tu código... Ve a [ask] para más información

Comment: te acabo de subir el codigo, la idea es subir las fotos a firebase para que en el oninit recupere las fotos y se muestren al cargar la pagina